# Overeating and eating too much

Tags: sentence-usage

Suppose a mother is advising her son who eats too much; then which one of the following sentences would be correct:

> - Gluttony is harmful to one’s health.
> - Overeating is harmful to one’s health.

---

> - Don’t eat too much.
> - Don’t over eat.

For me all of the above sentences sound idiomatic and natural.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Gluttony**, being one of the [Seven Deadly Sins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seven_deadly_sins), is a severe form of **overeating** and is indeed harmful to one's health.  Such people are referred to as [**gourmands**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gourmand).

One would usually advise against **overeating** before advising against **gluttony**.

In possible order of severity

> eating
>   eating too much
>   **overeating**
>   stuffed
>   can't eat anymore
>   **gluttony**

One can use the admonishments

> Don’t eat too much.
>   Don’t over eat.

because

> Overeating is harmful to one’s health.

People are not usually warned against the extreme **gluttony**.

The **gluttony gourmand** was a **glutton** for punishment.

Comment: Thank you @peter; just one more related question. Can you please tell me which one of the following sentences is more idiomatic and natural: "Don’t be so gluttonous" --- "Don’t be so overeater" --- "Don't overeat this much" --- Don't eat this much".

Comment: The natural usage would be "Don't be so gluttonous!" which would be said to a friend or someone you are familiar with, as in "Stop eating you gluttonous pig!" *(half kidding with a wink in your eye)* and "Don't overeat **so** much!" Using **this** you would need an example to point to, as in *Le Grande Bouffe*, "Don't eat **this** much!" pointing to a picture from the movie.  It should also not to be confused with the slang "don't eat this much" meaning "I don't have this to eat very often"